# How to load custom events with Azure Monitor SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` SDK package for accessing Azure Monitor metrics like this:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal("some-client-id", "some-client-secret", "some-tenant-id", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
   .Configure()
   .Authenticate(credentials)
   .WithSubscription("my-subscription");

foreach (var metricDefinition in azure.MetricDefinitions.ListByResource("my-resource-uri"))
{
    ...
}
```

It works fine for common metrics (Application Insights standard metrics). But how can I get my custom events with this SDK to render them in my custom app dashboard? I see recorded events in Application Insights dashboard under "Log-based metrics", but ListByResource method doesn't return them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this may be a bug.

The method `ListByResource` has 2 parameters, the 2nd one is `metricnamespace`.

By default, the `metricnamespace` is `microsoft.insights/components`, which is used for `Application Insights standard metrics`.

For `Log-based metrics`, the `metricnamespace` should be `microsoft.insights/components/kusto`(to check the value, you can use tools like `Fiddler` or `developer tool of any browser`). As per my test, when use `ListByResource("resourceId","microsoft.insights/components/kusto")`, it throws a "bad request" error. So I raised [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/1012) to track this.